# Implement filters with counters

Tags: mysql, sql

**What I want to achieve:**

I am developing website with a catalog of products.
This is normalized model (simplified) of entities which are related to my question:

[image]

So some product features exist (like size and type in this example), which all have predefined sets of values (e.g. sizes 1, 2 and 3 exist, and type may be 1, 2 or 3 (these sets do not have to be equal, just example.)).
Relationship between Product and each of features is "many-to-many" - different values of one feature do not exclude each other.
My task is to build form which will allow user to filter search results, based on features of products. Example screenshot:

[image]

Multiple checked values of one feature are mixed using "AND" logic, so if I have sizes One and Three checked, I need all products, which have both sizes (+ may have any other sizes, that doesn't matter, but selected ones must be present).

Number near each value of feature represents amount of products, which is  returned if user checks this value right now. So it is effectively a number of products satisfying filter "current active filter + this one value applied".

When user checks/unchecks any value, counters must be updated considering new "current filter".

**Problem:**

Real use case is: ~200k products, ~6 features with ~5-15 values each.
My `COUNT` queries, (especially with decent number of selected options) are too slow, and to render the form I need as many of these counts as there are values of all filters - in total that gives unacceptable response time.

**What I have tried:**

- Query to retrieve results:

  ```
  select * from products p, product_size ps
  where p.id = ps.product_id
  and (ps.size_id IN (1, 2, 3, 5))
  group by p.id
  having count(p.id) = 4;
  ```

(this is to select products which have sizes 1, 2, 3 and 5 at the same time).
It completes in `~0.360` sec on 120k products, almost same time with `COUNT` wrapped around it. And this query does not allow more than one feature (but I could place values of all features in one table).

- Another query to retrieve the same set:

  ```
  SELECT ps1.product_id
  FROM product_size AS ps1, (SELECT id FROM size AS s1 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 5)) AS t
  WHERE ps1.size_id = t.id
  GROUP BY ps1.product_id
  HAVING COUNT(ps1.size_id) = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (SELECT id FROM size AS s2 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 5)) AS t2);
  ```

It completes in `~0.230` sec (same time when wrapped in `COUNT`) and does not allow multiple features too.
It is modified query I found here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/ (second query in "Division with a Remainder" part).

- Alternative schema:
  [image]

Denormalized model, where value of each feature is a boolean column in Products table.
The query is obvious here:

```
    select * from products
    where `size_1` = 1 and `size_2` = 1
      and `size_3` = 1 and `size_5` = 1;
```

Weird and harder to maintain in application's code, but completes in `~0.056` sec when `COUNT`-ing.

None of these methods are acceptable per se because multiplied ~30 times (to populate all counters in form) that gives inadequate response time.

- Caching and precomputing
  Data in DB is going to be updated only few times a day (like, may be, even 2), so I could probably precompute counts for all combinations of filters when data is updated (I haven't measured necessary time to be honest), but it is anyway not going to work too - search form has fields with  arbitrary values (like min/max price and text search by the product's name), which I can't precompute for.
- Load counters in form dynamically
  Render form, but fetch numbers through AJAX, so user would be able to see page, and then, after quite long waiting, numbers. This is my last thought, but it seems like poor quality of service for me (may be it is worse than no counters at all).

I am stuck. Any hints? May be I am not seeing some bigger picture? I would be very glad to any advice.

**UPDATE**: if we forget about counters, what is the effective and usually used way (query) for just retrieving results with such a filters (or what am I doing wrong)? Like "find post with all requested tags" model, that is equivalent. I suspect it can be faster than my `0.230` sec (query #2), considering small (?) amount of rows for MySQL.

Comment: This might sound stupid, could you cache each size rather that querying for 3 at once and add them (this can be good because if the parameters change you should have each value cached[at least 50-60% percent of the time). You could have a cache decorator on top of your service to check if a size is in cache, else query and cache it

Comment: @ka_lin, I do not quite understand you, what do you mean by "add them"?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Query each size individually then add the results (numeric) is what I was trying to say.

Comment: @jarlh, what this has to do with my question? Sorry, may be I miss something, but AFAIK, queries breaking the rule which you quoted here would fail with error if being run, aren't they? I do not see problems with this rule in my queries.

Comment: @ka_lin, what would I achieve with addition? I am sorry, probably it is my example which mislead you, but different values are not excluding each other - by querying "1, 2, 3 and 5 sizes" I have to get all products, each of which has all of these four sizes. It is just misleading "size" example.

Comment: @OlegArkhipov, so how did you achieve the same?

Comment: @shiva, I actually never did. Though now I would try to use Elasticsearch for this purpose, If I had to.

Comment: @OlegArkhipov Thanks. I will have to read on Elasticsearch.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Create one table which will store all possible combinations (product_id <> size_id <> type_id)
2. Update this table when Admin will make any changes in product from backend (assuming there will be a backend management)
3. In frontend, for filters, use this table instead of product tables, and extract product ids once filter query is fired
4. Once you have list of product ids for result, you can fetch actual data by using those product Ids

I have used this before, and it worked for me, you can first make table and try running query to check response time.

Hope this helps.